# Last update of a jena triplestore

Tags: jena

Is there a more reliable method of determining the last time a tdb was updated rather than just looking at the timestamp of journal.jrnl? I see that the `TDB` class has a `BUILD_DATE` constant, but when I run

```
TDB tdb = new TDB();
TDB.sync(dataset);
String b = TDB.BUILD_DATE;
System.out.println(b);
```

the resulting date bears no relevance to either when I created the `dataset` nor to any of the dates in the triplestore...

Comment: `BUILD_DATE` is when the TDB jar code was built.

Comment: There isn't a timestamp for the last change.  (and class TDB isn't the database - it's a collection of constants and system wide functions).